Synchronizing Tab States with Extension Scripts in a Multi-tab Browser Developed with C# WebView2
Content: I have developed a multi-tab browser using C# WebView2. For each new tab created, a WebView2 instance is instantiated. Suppose I created 3 instances. In the extension script, I use:
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) { console.log(tabs); // It should return an array of information for the currently active tab in the window });
to query the current active tab. Normally, it should only return the information of the active tab object, but the problem is that after executing the query, it returns 3 tab information entries that correspond to the previous 3 WebView2 instances, and all objects have the active property set to true, which is obviously incorrect.
Is this a bug in WebView2? Could anyone please help analyze this? Thank you very much.
I hope that when a new WebView2 instance is created, the display state of the WebView2 instance can be synchronized within the extension environment. The version of WebView2 I am using is 1.0.2535.41.

C is not C#. Don't tag the wrong language.
